# JSON Parsing Multiple Conditions

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm struggling to get desired output using JSON.parse from the below JSON input. I'm using javascript and basically, I need to get the ids of each category based on the category name. I have the names as conditions in my system now I need to get all the 3 ids.

JSON data:

```
{"TokenID": "9FBBD91BBB",
"OrgID": 0,
"OutputObject": {
    "SUBROOT": [{
        "Parent Category": "Hardware",
        "Parent CategoryId": 2,
        "Sub Category": "Computer",
        "Sub CategoryId ": 3,
        "Child Category": "CPU",
        "Child CategoryId": 4,
        "Tenant": "IT"
    },
    {
        "Parent Category": "Hardware",
        "Parent CategoryId": 2,
        "Sub Category": "Router",
        "Sub CategoryId ": 3,
        "Child Category": "Cisco",
        "Child CategoryId": 6,
        "Tenant": "IT"
    },
    {
        "Parent Category": "Software",
        "Parent CategoryId": 7,
        "Sub Category": "Windows",
        "Sub CategoryId ": 8,
        "Child Category": "Operating System",
        "Child CategoryId": 9,
        "Tenant": "IT"
    },
    {
        "Parent Category": "Software",
        "Parent CategoryId": 7,
        "Sub Category": "ERP",
        "Sub CategoryId ": 10,
        "Child Category": "SAP",
        "Child CategoryId": 11,
        "Tenant": "IT"
    }]
  }
}
```

Query

```
{
        "Parent Category": "Hardware",
        "Sub Category": "Router",
        "Child Category": "Cisco"
}
```

Desired Output:

```
"Parent CategoryId": 2,
"Sub CategoryId ": 3,
"Child CategoryId": 6
```

Comment: What are you parsing with?

Comment: Looks like you're missing some stuff in that JSON dump. And what language are you using? What do you want the results of getting these ids to look like?

Comment: @Shawn corrected JSON structure and trying to achieve using Javascript.

Comment: What's wrong with `JSON.parse`? Or when you said "parsing" did you mean "Working with objects and arrays after some JSON was parsed into a JavaScript data structure"? (Those are completely different things).

Comment: @Quentin, my bad, I've updated the question.

Comment: @Jakk Could you elaborate? Especially: *"...based on the category name. I have the names in my system but I need to get all the 3 ids..."* For example, add the complete input and desired output. It seems what you posted is just half of the input (*names in my system*).

Comment: I need to parse JSON based on multiple conditions and get the key-pair values of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to split the two requirements. First get all entries matching your query, then pluck the keys you need. For example:

```js
// match query against every entry in input
const match = (query, input) => input.filter((entry) => Object.entries(query).every(([k, v]) => entry[k] === v));

// pluck only the required keys from every entry in input
const pluck = (keys, input) => input.map((entry) => keys.reduce((acc, k) => ({...acc, [k]: entry[k]}), {}));

//////////

const input = {
  "TokenID": "9FBBD91BBB",
  "OrgID": 0,
  "OutputObject": {
    "SUBROOT": [
      {
        "Parent Category": "Hardware",
        "Parent CategoryId": 2,
        "Sub Category": "Computer",
        "Sub CategoryId ": 3,
        "Child Category": "CPU",
        "Child CategoryId": 4,
        "Tenant": "IT"
      },
      {
        "Parent Category": "Hardware",
        "Parent CategoryId": 2,
        "Sub Category": "Router",
        "Sub CategoryId": 3,
        "Child Category": "Cisco",
        "Child CategoryId": 6,
        "Tenant": "IT"
      },
      {
        "Parent Category": "Software",
        "Parent CategoryId": 7,
        "Sub Category": "Windows",
        "Sub CategoryId": 8,
        "Child Category": "Operating System",
        "Child CategoryId": 9,
        "Tenant": "IT"
      },
      {
        "Parent Category": "Software",
        "Parent CategoryId": 7,
        "Sub Category": "ERP",
        "Sub CategoryId": 10,
        "Child Category": "SAP",
        "Child CategoryId": 11,
        "Tenant": "IT"
      }
    ]
  }
};
const query = {
  "Parent Category": "Hardware",
  "Sub Category": "Router",
  "Child Category": "Cisco"
};

// apply
const matches = match(query, input.OutputObject.SUBROOT);
const reduced = pluck(['Parent CategoryId', 'Sub CategoryId', 'Child CategoryId'], matches);

console.log(reduced);
```